# How to read values from command line in bash script as given?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I want to pass arguments to a script in the form

```
    ./myscript.sh -r [1,4] -p [10,20,30]
```

where in *myscript.sh* if I do:

```
    echo $@
```

But I'm getting the output as

```
   -r 1 4 -p 1 2 3
```

How do I get output in the form of

```
   -r [1,4] -p [10,20,30]
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and bash version 4.2.37

Comment: I'm getting output like as you need:
Please add info about you OS and bash version 
cmd: `./test1.bash -r [1,4] -p [10,20,30]`  

output:
`-r [1,4] -p [10,20,30]`

Comment: I ran it using `zsh`, `csh`, `sh` and `bash` interpreter and they all returned your desired output...

Comment: bash version is irrelevant in this particular case.

Comment: Those aren't bash versions... But I get your point :)

Comment: Looks like [] are interptereted as {}. Is it possible that this behaviour is defined somewhere? What do you get if you try [1..10] ?

Comment: pepelac, shellfish, check my answer. If you manually create 4 files named 1, 2 3 & 4, you'll get similar o/p as OP.

Comment: `[]` & `{}` are not interpreted in same way. `[]` refers to filename expansion. `{}` does not require those files to be present.

Comment: On running `./myscript.sh [1..10]` I'm getting `1` instead of `[1..10]`. My bash version is `4.2.37`.

Comment: @abcdef, exactly the same explanation, with a different pattern. Read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion)

```
set -f
./myscript.sh -r [1,4] -p [10,20,30]
```

Don't expect other users to want to do this, if you share your script.

The best answer is anishane's:  just quote the arguments

```
./myscript.sh -r "[1,4]" -p "[10,20,30]"
```

Answer (score 4):

You have files named 1 2 3 & 4 in your working directory.

[Use more quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting).

```
./myscript.sh -r "[1,4]" -p "[10,20,30]"
```

`[1,4]` gets expanded by bash to filenames named `1` or `,` or `4` (whichever are actually present on your system).
Similarly, `[10,20,30]` gets expanded to filenames named `1` or `0` or `,` or `2` or `3`.

On similar note, you should also change `echo $@` to `echo "$@"`

On another note, if you really want to distinguish between the arguments, use `printf '%s\n' "$@"` instead of just `echo "$@"`.

Comment: Wow, brilliant. I would have searched for a while before figuring that out!

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "$@" ` is still giving me the same output. So does `echo "$@"`. I want the arguments to be read as is without adding any more quotes.

Comment: @abcdef, then you need to remove those files so that the [shell patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) (`[1,4]` and `[10,20,30]`) no longer match them. The safe way is to use more quotes when you call your script.

Comment: "I want the arguments to be read as is without adding any more quotes": `[1,4]` will get expanded to `1 4` as read by script. `"[1,4]"` will be read as `[1,4]` by the script. `"\"[1,4]\""` will get read as `"[1,4]"`. Second option is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can just the escape the brackets`[]`. Like this,

```
./verify.sh  -r \[1,4\] -p \[10,20,30\]
```

You can print this using the `echo "$@"`